# I got list of tuples instead of dictionary in robot framework

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

I wanted to read an excel file, so I wrote these keywords in robot framework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     ExcelLibrary
Library     Collections

Resource    ../Variables/ConstantVariables.robot
Resource    ../Variables/ConfigVariables.robot

*** Variables ***


*** Keywords ***
Read Data From Excel
    [Arguments]     ${filename}    ${sheetname}
    open excel      ${filename}
    @{excel_result} =   Create List
    ${rows} =   get_row_count   ${sheetname}
    :FOR    ${rindex}   IN RANGE    1   ${rows}
    \   ${ret_val} =      Get Row Values     ${sheetname}    ${rindex}
    \    Append To List      ${excel_result}    ${ret_val}

    [Return]    ${excel_result}

Get All Values of the Row
    [Arguments]     ${sheetname}    ${rowindex}
    ${cols} =   get_column_count   ${sheetname}
    ${vals} =   Create Dictionary
    ${titles} =     get_row_values      ${sheetname}    0
    :FOR    ${cindex}   IN RANGE    0   ${cols}
    \    ${val} =    read_cell_data_by_coordinates       ${sheetname}       ${cindex}        ${rowindex}
    \    Set To Dictionary   ${vals}    ${titles[0]}     ${val}

    [Return]    ${vals}
```

This is the scenario file:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../Variables/ConstantVariables.robot
Resource    ../Variables/ConfigVariables.robot
Resource    ../Keywords/CommonKeywords.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Test For Loop
    @{ret_val} =    Read Data From Excel    ${jobfilename}      ${jobsheetname}
    log to console      ${ret_val}
```

This is the output I've got:

```
PS D:\Abbasimazar\workspace\RobotTests\Scenarios> pybot .\scenario.robot
==============================================================================
Scenario
==============================================================================
Test For Loop                                                         .[[('A2', u't1'), ('B2', u'n1'), ('C2', u'c1')], [
('A3', u't2'), ('B3', u'n2'), ('C3', u'c2')], [('A4', u't3'), ('B4', u'n3'), ('C4', u'c3')]]
Test For Loop                                                         | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenario                                                              | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  D:\Abbasimazar\workspace\RobotTests\Scenarios\output.xml
Log:     D:\Abbasimazar\workspace\RobotTests\Scenarios\log.html
Report:  D:\Abbasimazar\workspace\RobotTests\Scenarios\report.html
```

But I expected to get this:

```
[{'A2': u't1', 'B2': u'n1', 'C2': u'c1'}, {'A3': u't2', 'B3': u'n2', 'C3': u'c2'}, {'A4': u't3', 'B4': u'n3', 'C4': u'c3'}]
```

Any Idea what I did wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

As @ombre42 said, there was a mistake in calling keywords. I should change the line:

```
${ret_val} =      Get Row Values     ${sheetname}    ${rindex}
```

into:

```
${ret_val} =      Get All Values of the Row     ${sheetname}    ${rindex}
```

But after that I noticed the line

```
${titles} =     get_row_values      ${sheetname}    0
```

gives me this:

```
==============================================================================
Scenario
==============================================================================
Test For Loop                                                         .[{('A1', u'test'): u'c1'}, {('A1', u'test'): u'c2
'}, {('A1', u'test'): u'c3'}]
Test For Loop                                                         | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenario                                                              | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

So I wrote new method to get titles:

```
Get Titles From Sheet
    [Arguments]     ${sheetname}
    ${cols} =   get_column_count   ${sheetname}
    @{titles} =   Create List
    :FOR    ${cindex}   IN RANGE    0   ${cols}
    \    ${val} =    read_cell_data_by_coordinates       ${sheetname}       ${cindex}        0
    \    Append To List      ${titles}    ${val}

    [Return]    ${titles}
```

and changed that line to:

```
${titles} =     Get Titles From Sheet      ${sheetname}
```

Now the result is as I wanted:

```
==============================================================================
Scenario
==============================================================================
Test For Loop                                                         .[{u'test': u't1', u'name': u'n1', u'class': u'c1'
}, {u'test': u't2', u'name': u'n2', u'class': u'c2'}, {u'test': u't3', u'name': u'n3', u'class': u'c3'}]
Test For Loop                                                         | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenario                                                              | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Read Data From Excel* calls *Get Row Values* and not *Get All Values of the Row*, which creates dictionaries. *Get All Values of the Row* is not used in the code provided.

Perhaps you are thinking that *Read Data From Excel* is using your user keyword when it in fact is using the library keyword.

Comment: Yes, you are right; that was a mistake in using the keywords which I did not notice. Thank you. I also changed some other parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is an OrderedDict? OrderedDicts representation looks like a list of tuples:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d['x'] = 1
>>> d
OrderedDict([('x', 1)])
```

Even if it is a regular list of tuples instead of an OrderedDict, it is trivial to convert them to a dict, as the dict constructor can take a list of tuples directly:

```
>>> dict([('x', 1)])
{'x': 1}
```

Comment: I know how to do it in python, I want to do it in robot framework keywords. But thank you for noticing ordered dictionaries; I'll try to find out what is the exact type of dictionary in robot framework.